# jquery on click works only two times

Tags: jquery

my on click function works only for two times. After the second click nothing more happens? What can it caused?

```
$(document).on('click', '.load_content', function(){
    console.log('click to load');
});
```

Comment: You can share your HTML

Comment: you can check my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mmezlini/f28jxhse/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function(){
    $('.load_content').click(function() {
         console.log('click to load');
    });
});
```

Add this Code at the root level. You can try this code hopefully, it works fine for all cases.

Comment: i've it inside this, but if i add this under the existing one it works. Why it is so?